# Split dictionary key and list of values from dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to split keys and values and display the dictionary result below mentioned format. I'm reading a file and splitting the data into list and later moving to dictionary.

Please help me to get the result.

**INPUT FILE** - commands.txt

```
login url=http://demo.url.net username=test@url.net password=mytester

create-folder foldername=demo

select-folder foldername=test123

logout
```

**Expected result format**

```
print result_dict


        "0": {
            "login": [
                {
                    "url": "http://demo.url.net",
                    "username": "test@url.net",
                    "password": "mytester"
                }
            ]
        },
        "1": {
            "create-folder": {
                "foldername": "demo"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "select-folder": {
                "foldername": "test-folder"
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "logout": {}
        }
```

**CODE**

```
    file=os.path.abspath('catalog/commands.txt')
    list_output=[f.rstrip().split() for f in open(file).readlines()]
    print list_output

    counter=0
    for data in list_output:
        csvdata[counter]=data[0:]
        counter=counter+1   
    print csvdata

for key,val in csvdata.iteritems():
    for item in val:
        if '=' in item:
            key,value=item.split("=")
            result[key]=value

print result
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create JSON. Use the builtin `json` module for that task.

Comment: Ye, but he first needs the data correctly in an dict for that.

Comment: Why is `login` a list of dicts in the expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a function:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

def read_file(file_path):
    result = defaultdict(dict)
    item = count()
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line:
                continue
            parts = line.split()
            result[next(item)][parts[0]] = dict(p.split('=') for p in parts[1:])
    return dict(result)
```

Better example and explanation:

```
s = """
login url=http://demo.url.net username=test@url.net password=mytester

create-folder foldername=demo

select-folder foldername=test123

logout
"""

from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

result_dict = defaultdict(dict)
item = count()

# pretend you opened the file and are reading it line by line
for line in s.splitlines():
    if not line:
        continue # skip empty lines
    parts = line.split()
    result_dict[next(item)][parts[0]] = dict(p.split('=') for p in parts[1:])
```

With pretty print:

```
>>> pprint(dict(result_dict))
{0: {'login': {'password': 'mytester',
               'url': 'http://demo.url.net',
               'username': 'test@url.net'}},
 1: {'create-folder': {'foldername': 'demo'}},
 2: {'select-folder': {'foldername': 'test123'}},
 3: {'logout': {}}}
```

Comment: The code is more helpful for me and implemented the same. I want some more information, how to extract the key,value and store into txt file. I have created the following logic to get required information like username,url,password,create-folder and writing into txt file. `code` def extract_value(dict_in,dict_out):for key,value in dict_in.iteritems():if isinstance(value,dict): extract_value(value,dict_out)else:dict_out[key] = value return dict(dict_out)`code`. The code is extracting but already exist  key : value is replaced by latest iteration value. How can I avoid this kind of scenario.

Comment: You should ask another question, be as detailed as you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = ["login url=http://demo.url.net username=test@url.net password=mytester",
         "create-folder foldername=demo",
         "select-folder foldername=test123",
         "logout"]

result = {}
for no, line in enumerate(lines):
    values = line.split()
    pairs = [v.split('=') for v in values[1:]]
    result[str(no)] = {values[0]: [dict(pairs)] if len(pairs) > 1 else dict(pairs)}

import pprint
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
{'0': {'login': [{'password': 'mytester',
                  'url': 'http://demo.url.net',
                  'username': 'test@url.net'}]},
 '1': {'create-folder': {'foldername': 'demo'}},
 '2': {'select-folder': {'foldername': 'test123'}},
 '3': {'logout': {}}}
```

But are you sure you need the extra list inside the `login` value? If not, just change `[dict(pairs)] if len(pairs) > 1 else dict(pairs)` to `dict(pairs)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = dict()
f = open('commands.txt')

for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
  r[str(i)] = dict()
  actions = line.split()
  list_actions = {}
  for action in actions[1:]:
    if "=" in action:
      k, v = action.split('=')
      list_actions[k] = v
  if len(actions[1:]) > 1:
    r[str(i)][actions[0]] = [list_actions]
  else:
    r[str(i)][actions[0]] = list_actions


print r
```

Should be work

Comment: You should make sure to `f.close()` at the end of your code - or use the recommended `with open(FILE) as f` method.