# Split multiple nested key,values and extract to text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to split the nested key and value from dict and write into text file. I have  tried the following code to extract the nested key and values. But the key's values are overwritten by latest iteration result. Extracted the result will be using to selenium input parameter.

Reference - [Split dictionary key and list of values from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683667/split-dictionary-key-and-list-of-values-from-dict)

Please let me know to get my result.

**EXPECTED TXT FILE**

```
step0.username=test@url.net
step0.url=http://demo.url.net 
step0.password=mytester
step0.create-folder-name=demo
step1.url=http://demo.url.net 
step1.username=test123@url.net 
step1.password=mytester123
step1.select-folder-name=demo124
step1.share-folder-name=demo124
```

**INPUT FILE** - list of action to be performed on my project.

```
login url=http://demo.url.net username=test@url.net password=mytester
create-folder create-folder-name=demo
logout
login url=http://demo.url.net username=test123@url.net password=mytester123
select-folder  select-folder-name=demo124
share-folder share-folder-name=demo124
logout
```

The following code is parsing the input file.

```
def read_file(file_path):
    result = defaultdict(dict)
    item = count()
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line:
                continue
            parts = line.split()
            result[next(item)][parts[0]] = dict(p.split('=') for p in parts[1:])
    return dict(result)
```

The following to code to split the nested key and value and storing into text file.

```
def generate_properties_file(filepath,dict_in):
    try:
        print "File PATH" , filepath
        print "Generating user property file - %s" %(filepath)
        with open(filepath,'wb') as f:
            for key,value in dict_in.iteritems():
                output_result ='\n'+str(key)+'='+str(value)
                f.write(output_result)
    except IOError:
        print "Unable to write the file :%s " %(filepath)

def extract_value(dict_in,dict_out):
    for key,value in dict_in.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value,dict):     #if value as a dictionary
            extract_value(value,dict_out)
        elif isinstance(value,list):    # if value in a list
            for i in value:
                extract_value(i,dict_out)
        else:
            dict_out[key] = value
    return dict(dict_out)

def get_property(file_path):
    lib_dict = {}
    results = read_file(file)
    myextracted_data = extract_value(results,lib_dict)
    generate_properties_file(os.path.abspath('catalog/user.properties'),myextracted_data)

if __name__=='__main__':

    file = os.path.abspath('catalog/commands.txt')
    get_property(file)
```

Above code is working fine with following command feed and generating the text property file.

```
login url=http://demo.url.net username=test@url.net password=mytester
create-folder create-folder-name=demo select-folder select-folder-name=demo logout
```

**Generated the OUTPUT File**

```
username=test123@url.net
select-folder-name=demo124
share-folder-name=demo124
create-folder-name=demo
url=http://demo.url.net
password=mytester123
```

Comment: Can you show us how are you calling this function and what output you obtain? I don't understand why you are using the `extract_value` function, so provide an example usage will clarify what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you currently have *cannot* work because using `dict`s you lose information on the order of the steps. However I believe there is a much easier solution:

```
from itertools import count, groupby

def make_login_key():
    counter = count()
    current_key = None
    def key(line):
        nonlocal current_key
        if line.startswith('login'):
            # we found the start of a new step, so change key
            current_key = next(counter)
        return current_key
    return key

def find_steps(fobj):
    for _, group in groupby(fobj, key=make_login_key()):
        step = []
        for line in group:
            step.extend(line.split()[1:])
        yield step



def format_steps(steps, fobj):
    for i, step in enumerate(steps):
        for part in step:
            fobj.write('step{}.{}={}\n'.format(i, *part.split('=')))
```

Example usage:

```
In [2]: from io import StringIO

In [3]: input_file = StringIO('''login url=http://demo.url.net username=test@url.net password=mytester
   ...: create-folder create-folder-name=demo
   ...: logout
   ...: login url=http://demo.url.net username=test123@url.net password=mytester123
   ...: select-folder  select-folder-name=demo124
   ...: share-folder share-folder-name=demo124
   ...: logout''')

In [4]: output_file = StringIO()

In [5]: format_steps(find_steps(input_file), output_file)

In [6]: print(output_file.getvalue())
step0.url=http://demo.url.net
step0.username=test@url.net
step0.password=mytester
step0.create-folder-name=demo
step1.url=http://demo.url.net
step1.username=test123@url.net
step1.password=mytester123
step1.select-folder-name=demo124
step1.share-folder-name=demo124
```

If you replace the `StringIO`s with actual file it should the same.

---

**Note:** The above code assumes python3 (in particular the `nonlocal` statement).
It's pretty easy to work around. A simple way is to use a `list`:

```
def make_login_key():
    counter = count()
    current_key = [None]
    def key(line):
        if line.startswith('login'):
            current_key[0] = next(counter)
        return current_key[0]
    return key
```

This works since `current_key[0] = next(counter)` does **not** assign to `counter_key`. It's a call to the `__setitem__` method of the `current_key`.

(I remind that `nonlocal` and `global` are useful *if and only if* you *assign* to the variables. If you do not assign you can safely omit them).

Comment: This is more helpful for my project.

Comment: Looks like nonlocal keyword work with python 3.x and not in python 2.7

Comment: @raj Yes. It's easy to workaround. For example you could use `current_key = [None]` and instead of doing `current_key = next(counter)` do `current_key[0] = next(counter)`. Note that you do not have to use `nonlocal counter` since you never assign to it (now I'll update my answer).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're overcomplicating things a bit. How about

```
import re

def parse(fp):
    c = -1
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('login'):
            c += 1
        for k, v in re.findall(r'(\S+?)=(\S+)', line):
            yield 'step{}.{}={}\n'.format(c, k, v)
```

and then

```
with open(INPUT) as fin, open(OUTPUT, 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(parse(fin))
```